# String Manipulation - How I say to excel "If the letter "v" and a number appear together"?

Tags: excel, vba

[Scroll down to the end for the very short version!]

Just to let you know this is my second time I have ever posted on a website forum and also I am brand new to coding but am definitely pick it (albeit extremely slowly!) and really enjoying it.

Background to the problem:

In my organisation there is a requirement to save files in accordance with a particular naming convention, which is as follows:

```
YYYY-MM-DDFilenamewithoutspacesorspecialcharactersandfirstlettercapitalisedVxx.xx.fileextension
```

Where `Vxx.xx` represents the version number which MUST be written using 2 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after.

E.g. `2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV01.00.doc`.

I have created a macro that loops through all files and folders, returns the current names and renames the files (if they are incorrect) based on user populated alternatives (written in a "New Name" column next to the "Original Name" column).

The task at hand:

I am trying to automate the population of the "New Name" column as much as possible but am stuck on correcting the version number.

I have found that there are essentially 5 different ways to get the version number wrong and have summarised these below along with how they would be correct:

- V1 - Should be changed to "V01.00"
- V10 - Should be changed to "V10.00"
- V1.1 - Should be changed to "V01.10"
- V10.1 - Should be changed to "V10.10"
- V1.10 - Should be changed to "V01.10"

The key find I want from the formula is to be able to identify `"V" & Number` within a text string and where it is found, to amend in accordance with the above.

I also want it to ignore instances of "Nov1" as these appear many times e.g. "Nov18Accounts" etc.

I am not entirely sure if this can be done on Excel itself or whether the VBE is required hence tagged both of them in the post.

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you.

---

Short Version:

Is it possible to identify `"V" & Number` within a text string to return instances of when they appear together?
E.g. for "StackoverflowquestionV1.00.doc" in an Excel cell, can I use a function to find "V1" and replace with 01? The "V" will always be the same but the numbers will change.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: *can I use a function to find "V1" and replace with 01?* Yes, it's called `Replace` **but** watch out, because if the filename is `V10.00` it will replace it too! So you need to isolate first the string you want to change. Have you tried starting at the end of the string? Looking at your data example, looks like your filenames always (excluding extension) end with 6 chars, that must be type  `Vxx.xx` where `x` is an integer between 0 and 9. Try to get the last 6 chars from each filename and then replace there if needed.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. The convention is SUPPOSED to end uniformly however it seldom is hence why I have been given the task to clean it up. Going forward however it will be cleaned up on a monthly basis but not by me hence trying to automate the function. Also it won't always be V1 it will always be V and any number from 0-9. I am aware of search/find/replace/substitute however not sure how so say "look for the letter "V" and a number together"...

Comment: Do you create those filenames yourself, i.e. do you have a chance to modified the format of the naming convention? If so, change the "Vxx.xx" to something clearly identifiable as the start of the version information, e.g. "-Vxx.xx". That way you can search for "-V" and have a clear indication that that's where the version numbers start. If that's not possible, try tackling the string from the end, e.g. strip off the file extension first, then locate the "V" with InStrRev().

Comment: It's unclear how wrong your file names can get. With the requirement of  `namewithoutspacesorspecialcharactersandfirstlettercapitalised`, it is easy to ignore the `Nov18Accounts`, but the fact you have to rename the files to begin with means that you might have the non-lowercase `NOV18Accounts` which will be replaced to `NOV18.00Accounts`. In fact, the very example of `Nov18Accounts` breaks the rules by having additional capitalized letters.

Comment: @HelO'Ween - Thank you for your response. The naming convention is very strict. The tool I am creating, no hyphens allowed other than the 2 in the date. InStrRev() is something I have never heard of or used so will look into that and hopefully that will help solve it!

Comment: @GSerg - Apologies, perhaps shouldn't have mentioned the other criteria as date/case sensitivity is something I can handle. It's just being able to identify the V & [A number] together in a string. If there is a way to code the 5 different variations as cases in VBA code (I am new to VBA but from what I gather this might be a possibility?) e.g. If V&SingleDigit&"." Then change to V&"0"&SingleDigit&"." etc. and ignore the 6th in the case of Nov1. Hope I'm making sense and apologies for over-complicating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Public Function NormalizeVersionNumbers(ByVal s As String) As String
  NormalizeVersionNumbers = s

  With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")  ' New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "V\.?([0-9]{1,2})(\.([0-9]{1,2}))?(?=.{0,8}\.*?$)"

    With .Execute(s)
      Dim i As Long

      For i = .Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        NormalizeVersionNumbers = Left$(NormalizeVersionNumbers, .Item(i).FirstIndex) & Format$(CLng(.Item(i).SubMatches(0)), "V00") & Format$(CLng(.Item(i).SubMatches(2)), "\.00") & Mid$(NormalizeVersionNumbers, .Item(i).FirstIndex + .Item(i).Length + 1)
      Next
    End With

  End With

End Function
```

It should be noted that it (in my opinion correctly) converts `V1.1` to `V01.01` as opposed to `V01.10`. If that is in fact not desired, do something to that second `CLng` (such as multiplying it by 10).

Comment: Thank you this is brilliant! I should have specified in the question but I did actually want it as a function and that's what you've done. Also, having thought about it, I agree with your suggestion to name as V1.1 to V01.01 so will keep as is!

Comment: If it's not too much effort, could a minor amendment be made. There are 2 things I have noticed. 1) If there happens to be a "V#" anywhere in the file name it currently changes it in all areas. I know this is what I asked for but on reflection, is it easy enough to only conduct the search for "V#" on say the last 8 digits before the file extension? 2) Again didn't mention in the question however there are 2 more variations of "wrong" I would like it to correct - "V.x" and "V.xx". Is it easy enough to include these? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gserg. I might be pushing my luck here but final (promise) linked question: once the "Vxx.xx" has been corrected, although it is only searching within the last 8 characters from the file extension can it actually be MOVED so that the "Vxx.xx" will always appear as "Vxx.xx.fileextension". So "FilenameV01.00sr.ext" becomes "FilenamesrV01.00.ext"? I know this sounds awfully pedantic but with millions of documents on the shared drive, every little bit of automation helps.

Comment: @Haris Then you have to guarantee there is an extension (not currently a requirement) and that there is only one V part in the string (currently can be several). If you guarantee that, find the last period position with `InStrRev`, take out the middle `Format() & Format()` part, change the trailing `Mid$()` part to be only up to the period position by providing the third argument, paste the cut out `Format() & Format()` after that, and add yet another `Mid$()` with two arguments, just like the original unamended `Mid$()`, but this time starting at the period position, not at FirstIndex+Length.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Like operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator). In the column "A" of "Sheet1" write this 7 rows

1. V01.00
2. V10
3. V1.1
4. V10.10
5. V01.10
6. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV01.00.doc
7. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV1.00.doc

Then add this code to Module1:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim LRow As Long
    LRow = LastRow(Sheets("Sheet1"), 1)
    Dim LookArray As Variant
    LookArray = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & LRow)
    Dim Item As Long
    For Item = 1 To UBound(LookArray)
        If Not LookArray(Item, 1) Like "*V##.##*" Then
            Debug.Print ("BAD")
        Else
            Debug.Print ("OK")
        End If
    Next Item
End Sub

Public Function LastRow(ByRef wsSheet_I As Worksheet, ByVal lColumn_I _
  As Long) As Long
    Dim LRow As Range
    Set LRow = wsSheet_I.Columns(lColumn_I).Find(What:="*", _
                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:= _
                 xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not LRow Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = LRow.Row
    Else
        LastRow = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Then press Ctrl+G and you will see in Debugg window:

OK

BAD

BAD

OK

OK

OK

BAD

LastRow function returns the last row of a column even if there are empty rows. I prefer to use it instead of other codes like `End(xlUp).Row` `Range.Rows.Count` etc.

I use a loop with a range array because it is faster than a range loop

Comment: The idea was to *"renames the files (if they are incorrect)"*, not just report if they are wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your replies people I am working through them. @Malamare just tried your code and that is great for testing whether or not the version number is in the correct format (tested for 60 files and results were correct in every case) however as GSerg has mentioned it does not then go on to correct them which is the required functionality. If this bit could be added it would be great.

Comment: @Haris, have you tried the next answer I sent? I think it corrects the problems using another perspective. In addition, it only searches the last characters of the file name. There are no problems with the "V" in other places in the character string.

Comment: @Malamare - Thank you for this I did try and this did also seem to work quite well although didn't test on a big enough sample given that GSerg's solution has also worked very well and can use as a function rather than a sub procedure which although not specified, is better suited to my current needs. Very much appreciate your input though and would also tick yours as the answer but can only tick one I'm afraid!

Comment: If you have thousands of file names I would not use a function call at a time. It would take a long, long time. Use the code you use put all in a array and review them with the best code in a loop of the array. You can reduce the time by tens or hundreds. Use the function call to check after the user enters the name correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as GSerg suggests this is the code to rename the files. Only looks for patterns at the end of the file name, after the "V" before the extension. Keep in mind that there may be similar patterns along the file name and those must be discarded.

Copy this 6 rows at Sheet1 column A:

1. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV1.doc
2. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV10.doc
3. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV1.1.doc
4. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV10.1.doc
5. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV1.10.doc
6. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV01.00.doc

And paste this code in a Module1:

```
Option Explicit

Sub prueba()
    Dim LRow As Long
    LRow = LastRow(Sheets("Sheet1"), 1)
    Dim LookArray As Variant
    LookArray = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & LRow)
    Dim Item As Long
    Dim VersAndExt As String
    Dim Version As String
    Dim Extension As String
    Dim VersionOK As String
    For Item = 1 To UBound(LookArray)
        VersAndExt = Right$(LookArray(Item, 1), Len(LookArray(Item, 1)) _
          - InStrRev(LookArray(Item, 1), "V"))
        Version = Left$(VersAndExt, InStrRev(VersAndExt, ".") - 1)
        Extension = Right$(VersAndExt, Len(VersAndExt) _
          - InStrRev(VersAndExt, ".") + 1)
        Select Case Len(Version)
        Case 1 'V1 error
            VersionOK = "V" & "0" & Version & ".00"
        Case 2 'V10 error
            VersionOK = "V" & Version & ".00"
        Case 3 'V1.1
            VersionOK = "V" & "0" & Version & "0"
        Case 4
            If InStr(Version, ".") = 3 Then
                'V10.1
                VersionOK = "V" & Version & "0"
            Else
                'V1.10
                VersionOK = "V" & "0" & Version
            End If
        Case 5 'OK version
            VersionOK = "V" & Version
        End Select
        LookArray(Item, 1) = Replace(LookArray(Item, 1), "V" & _
          VersAndExt, VersionOK & Extension)
    Next Item
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D" & LRow) = LookArray
End Sub

Public Function LastRow(ByRef wsSheet_I As Worksheet, ByVal lColumn_I _
  As Long) As Long
    Dim LRow As Range
    Set LRow = wsSheet_I.Columns(lColumn_I).Find(What:="*", _
                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:= _
                 xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not LRow Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = LRow.Row
    Else
        LastRow = 0
    End If
End Function
```

You will see in Sheet1 column D this names

1. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV01.00.doc
2. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV10.00.doc
3. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV01.10.doc
4. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV10.10.doc
5. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV01.10.doc
6. 2019-07-24StackoverflowquestionV01.00.doc

Answer (score 0):

This approach is more basic and easier to understand then the advanced code from @GSerg: It uses `InStrRev` to identify the first "V" from the right(bypasses Nov issue), checks if there is a pattern match for the five possible incorrect user inputs, and if found will copy the cells value to the cell on the right, then using `Application.Replace` inserts new characters as needed. Comments are provided in the code.

```
Sub FixFileName()
Dim charPos As Integer, cel As Range

    For Each cel In Range("C6:C12") 'Loop thru each cell in the range
        charPos = InStrRev(cel.Value, "V") 'Use InStrRev to find the first "V" from the right

        'Each if statement will check the characters to the right starting at charPos for a pattern match,
        'if the cell matches then, the cell value will be copied to the cell to the right
        'The replace function will select the copied cell and then move to the charater where
        'you want to insert additional characters in
        'The first 0 after charPos, inserts characters, not replace any.
        'Note: If you wanted to replace the character you would use a 1, or a 2 to replce 2 characters
        'Additional Note: this code will skip all other values in the range that don't match.
        'If you identify other incorrect user inputs, you can easily add another ElseIf as needed

        If Mid(cel.Value, charPos, 6) Like "V#.#0." Then
            With cel.Offset(, 1)
                .Value = cel.Value
                .Value = Application.Replace(cel.Offset(, 1), charPos + 1, 0, "0")
            End With

        ElseIf Mid(cel.Value, charPos, 6) Like "V#0.#." Then
            With cel.Offset(, 1)
                .Value = cel.Value
                .Value = Application.Replace(cel.Offset(, 1), charPos + 5, 0, "0")
            End With

        ElseIf Mid(cel.Value, charPos, 5) Like "V#.#." Then
            With cel.Offset(, 1)
                .Value = cel.Value
                .Value = Application.Replace(cel.Offset(, 1), charPos + 4, 0, "0")
                .Value = Application.Replace(cel.Offset(, 1), charPos + 1, 0, "0")
            End With

        ElseIf Mid(cel.Value, charPos, 4) Like "V#0." Then
            With cel.Offset(, 1)
                .Value = cel.Value
                .Value = Application.Replace(cel.Offset(, 1), charPos + 4, 0, "00.")
             End With

        ElseIf Mid(cel.Value, charPos, 3) Like "V#." Then
            With cel.Offset(, 1)
                .Value = cel.Value
                .Value = Application.Replace(cel.Offset(, 1), charPos + 3, 0, "00.")
                .Value = Application.Replace(cel.Offset(, 1), charPos + 1, 0, "0")
            End With

        End If

    Next cel

End Sub
```